# How to load a 3D Animated Model in ios camera when it tracks a target image using openGl ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vuforia

I want to load a 3d animated model using OpenGl ES when the Camera starts from App and detects a Marker Image a 3d Animated Character Should Appear in my Camera . Can any one suggest some help or tutorials which can be usefull to me . I have already created a target image using vuforia but it only load 3d models  which is in .obj files  but now i want to load 
 3D Animated Model which has .md5 or .dae etc this kind extensions of model.

Comment: So your question is really how to load .dae or .md5 models instead of .obj ones?

Comment: yes .obj only supports 3d models  but not with animations , i want to load animated 3d models which are in .dae,.md5,.fbx and .ase file formats. it would be great if u suggest some help.